# How to write data in json file javascript not in node js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using below code in my chrome extension

```
function Writejson() {
    
    const fs = require("fs");
var student = { 
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 23, 
    gender: 'Male',
    department: 'English',
    car: 'Honda' 
};
 localStorage.setItem('myStorage', JSON.stringify(student));
var data = JSON.stringify(student, null, 2);
debugger;
fs.writeFile('input.json', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
     console.log('File data:', jsonString) 
});
 }
```

it's giving error "require is not defined" also i have added a file require.js then error is not coming but still data is not being saved into josn file..

Comment: You get the error " require is not defined " because `require()` does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript. Also, the `fs` module doesn't exist in the client side.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: You can create blob of type application/json, and download that file. Using this way, you can just write the file and download that, but can not perform any other operation on file.

Comment: fs is not present in chrome-extension. You can use fetch to get the file from remote API.

Comment: Is there any way to write the data in json file using javascript in chrome extension run time?

Comment: https://web.dev/file-system-access/